# Is there a way to work with instanced points independently when created from a grid?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

First post here!
So I created a grid of cubes from one cube in geometry nodes. I wanted to use the grid node as a way to quickly be able to create more cubes and have them automatically aligned and also be able to move every cube in an order. It's supposed to be apps in the end but I'm not there yet. It was really easy to just create a cube and then have them pop up on the instance according to the grid and now it's really easy to add more cubes, change the shape etc.

Anyways. Now I'm trying to find a way to move them independently from each other but still reference the "instance on points" node they were created on.

For example: animate one cube and have the animation ripple out to the others with a delayed effect. (maybe using value nodes set with #frames" Or have them animate on one at a time.

From what I've read if you create an "Realize Instances" node you're creating new geometry cubes from the "instance on points". Am I thinking right now? Or is the answer more mathematical that I need to get the position data for each point to single them out?

Or is the whole node tree wrong for what I want to do? (Treat the cubes as individual pieces after I've instanced them)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use realize instances, then you want to modify them, for example change the shape or add some vertex paint data. If you want just move, rotate, scale or assign the material - not only is it useless but also inefficient from performance side

Answer (score 6):

yes you can by using Position node.

[image]

[image]

Value has a driver with "#frame" in it. So it basically outputs the frame value.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed help will try the set position node. So you want to put it for the grid so that moves not the cubes itself:)

Comment: Please tap in the checkmark left of my answer, if it helped you. Thanks